# Using an Array to Transfer Coordinates To Be Placed on MkMapView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, coordinates, mkpointannotation

I have one view controller that lets the user input coordinates into textfields and updates these coordinates (as well as a title) into an array. In my MapView VC, I want to be able to place pins down according to what the user has inputed. However, when I run the code, the input coordinates are not read and nothing is placed on the MapView. I have a hunch that either I am not saving these locations properly, or my pin placing is not working, but I am not sure where the error could be.

Input Coordinates:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

// here I initialize my array locations
var locations: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = []

class OtherVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var latitudeField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var longitudeField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
var coordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// this IBOutlet takes the input from the textfield
@IBAction func addToMap(_ sender: Any) {
    let lat = latitudeField.text!
    let long = longitudeField.text!
    let title = titleTextField.text!
    let location: [String: Any] = ["title": title, "latitude": lat, "longitude": long]
    locations.append(location)

}
```

Below is the code for my MapView:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self


    //iterates each location in my array to pull the title and coordinate
    for location in locations {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = location["title"] as? String
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location["latitude"] as! Double, longitude: location["longitude"] as! Double)
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "pinAnnotation"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier) as? MKPinAnnotationView

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    }

    annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    return annotationView
}
}


}
```

Comment: Is the mapView being loaded after the user enters in the coordinates?

Comment: My app is structured as a tab controller, and in one tab is the MapView. So the mapView isn't loaded exactly after the user enters the coordinates, but the user can switch to the tab that has the mapView after.

Comment: The reason I ask is because it looks like you're iterating through your locations array in `viewDidLoad`, so if the view is loaded before the user has even entered a location, it's trying to iterate through an empty array, which would produce no result on the map. Try making your loop through the locations into it's own method, and then call the method at the end of `addToMap(_:)`